# What is the best approach to improve on Selenium webdriver project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What i have done :

- Created few projects using Java/ Selenium Webdriver/ TestNG using eclipse
- Getting the TestNG test results in an XML/ HTML formats and looking for failures etc.,

What i can look for hereafter,

- Do i need to use Maven(or likely tools), for managing projects, and why?
- Do i need to look for Jenkins type of tools(But i know it depends on context, still if there will be any real usability with selenium webdriver)
- Do i need to look for reporting tools(such as surefire) which is well equiped?
- Or is it ok to continue with what i'm doing for a not so complicated project?

I know this qustion may be really broad, but i don't find anything solid to look after.

Appreciate your help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the world has agreed that Continuous Integration is good which is pretty rare for any technology.

I would definitely suggest setting up jenkins or equivalent and adding the maven configuration to be able to get your project to run and store results there. This may end up being more work because ideally you want to get the project you are testing to be built on check in and have its unit tests etc to run and then get deployed so you can run your selenium tests.

It shouldnt take too long to do depending on the ease of deployment of the app your testing, but even just having your tests being able to be kicked off automatically and its results stored will be handy and give you a real visibility boost of your tests.